# Java Servlet: Unable to create Excel File

Tags: java, excel, servlets, apache-poi

I'm having difficulty getting a `Servlet` to create an `Excel file using apache POI`.

When I use the following code in a separate Java class it works fine, but when I copy the code into the servlet, the servlet just doesn't create the excel file.

This is essentially all that is in the servlet. I get parameters and just store those. I want to just get the servlet to create the file first, then start adding the user input in later.

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet 1");

Cell cell1 = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(3);
cell1.setCellValue("100000");
Cell cell2 = sheet.createRow(1).createCell(3);
cell2.setCellValue("Text text.");

FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("SampSamp.xls");
workbook.write(output);
output.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and the file is created in `c:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config` folder. Maybe you consider giving absolute path. For example : C:\temp\SamSamp.xls.